# nodejs + socket.io + ssh

Tags: node.js, socket.io, php, centos

Приветствую всех, не знаю, что за абракадабра такая происходит.

Установил nodejs и [socket.io](http://socket.io) на CentrOS через SSH(путти).

Если я завершаю сеанс SSH клиента, то доступ к сайту на nodejs+[socket.io](http://socket.io) становится не доступным. В чем может быть данная проблема?

Comment: А причём тут PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что NodeJS запускается как программа в консоли. Если закрыть консоль, то закроется и нода.

Самое простое это запускать ноду в скрине, т.е. выполнять команду screen после входа в консоль. Она создает как бы независимую консоль от твоего подключения. После запуска ноды таким образом ты можешь закрывать соединение. В будущем, для того, во вновь запущенном сеансе перейти к ноде, надо выполнить screen -r.

Answer (score 1):

еще хороший способ использовать forever

```
npm install -g forever
forever start /path/to/app.js
```